# How do I run the linux based docker container with tcsh as the shell instead of Bash?

Tags: linux, docker, shell

Here is the Dockerfile I am using with my goals specified within comment lines.

```
# Goal is to install dependencies such as csh and then 
# finish building an image where tcsh is the default shell 
# within the container. 
FROM centos:7
RUN set -e; \
    echo "# Install DRS dependencies csh and libjpeg"; \
    yum -y install csh --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="base"; \
# Setting the default shell of the user did not work either
# chsh -s /bin/tcsh;
SHELL ["/bin/tcsh", "-c"]
# I need to subsequently run csh scripts without having to 
# manually logon to the container, run tcsh, and then manually
# launch the script.  The application within the container
# is a native C++ application that relies on environment 
# variables set by a complex csh script
# Regardless of what I have tried, the shell running when the
# container launches is always bash
```

My interpretation of https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7281#issuecomment-389440503 is that the SHELL docker command should cause tcsh to be the default shell when I actually run a container based on the produced image.  Here is some command line output. After the image is built and a container is launched the default shell within the container is clearly still the bash shell.  My interpretation was obviously wrong.  How can I build the image such that the docker run command creates a container from the image where tcsh is the default instead of bash?  I have also tried to include 'chsh -s /bin/tcsh' as part of the RUN layer which did not work. Regardless of what I do the container always starts up running the bash shell, and the only way to cause tcsh to execute is by manually running a container interactively.  I need the container to start with tcsh as the shell so that environment scripts in csh can be executed.

> ```
> > $docker build -t centos-csh:v5 .
> Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
>
> Step 1/3 : FROM centos:7
>  ---> eeb6ee3f44bd
>
> Step 2/3 : RUN set -e;      echo "# Install dependencies";     yum -y install csh --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="base";
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 84b2f94f244c
>
> Step 3/3 : SHELL ["/bin/tcsh", "-c"]
>  ---> Running in 3042be550a34
> Removing intermediate container 3042be550a34
>  ---> 92d64253effe
> Successfully built 92d64253effe
> Successfully tagged centos-csh:v5
>
> $winpty docker run -it --name csh-5 centos-csh:v5
>
> [root@cfdb0280c39c /]# ps
>
>       PID TTY          TIME CMD
>     1 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
>     16 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
> ```

Comment: What's the actual program that's going to be running inside this container; why is having tcsh available important? Changing to a very different `SHELL` is likely to cause problems with, for example, the interpretation of `RUN` commands.

Comment: It is a legacy application that is being "containerized" which happens to depend on very complex csh scripts which I do not want to rewrite in bash.  In this prototyping stage I want to change as little as possible in terms of how the application currently executes.  However I only need tcsh to be running in the container.  It's fine for all of the RUN commands in the Dockerfile to be done by bash.  Maybe I'll decide to rewrite it in bash eventually or find another way to setup the env, but I didn't want to change very much about the app in my initial attempt.

Comment: If the scripts have a correct "shebang" line `#!/bin/tcsh` then you don't need to change anything at all, just make sure the shell is installed in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **ENTRYPOINT** and not **SHELL**.

Your Dockerfile should be like this:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN set -e; \
    yum -y install csh --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="base"

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tcsh"]
```

```bash
$ docker build -t centos-tcsh .
$ docker run -it --rm centos-tcsh
[root@0d427444c2e4 /]# ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 pts/0    00:00:00 tcsh
     21 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

However if you are using **RUN** in the Dockerfile after **SHELL** it will be running with tcsh.

```
FROM centos:7
RUN set -e; \
    yum -y install csh --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="base"
SHELL ["/bin/tcsh", "-c"]
RUN ps -A
```

```bash
$ docker build -t centos-tcsh .
[...]
Step 3/5 : SHELL ["/bin/tcsh", "-c"]
 ---> Running in f22514d13cca
Removing intermediate container f22514d13cca
 ---> e5a10966d0a1
Step 4/5 : RUN ps -A
 ---> Running in 0eaa2996c4ff
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 ?        00:00:00 tcsh
     12 ?        00:00:00 ps
Removing intermediate container 0eaa2996c4ff
[...]

$ docker run -it --rm centos-tcsh
[root@81df5c8b3061 /]# ps -A 
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
      1 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
     15 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

So **SHELL** is for the **RUN** during the build and **ENTRYPOINT** if for when you are using `docker run ...`

Comment: That is what I thought but I'm pretty sure I tried that without success.  I'll try once more and see.

Comment: @shawn1874 note that is `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tcsh"]` and not `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tcsh", "-c"]`

Comment: I tried that and it failed with this error " ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tcsh"]' returned a non-zero code: 127".  Also I am running Docker for Windows Desktop.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that tcsh must be installed in the git bash or cygwin environment on windows.  I would have thought that ENTRYPOINT is specifying what should run in the container and that the engine doesn't require it to also be installed on the host.  You might be running docker from within LInux.

Comment: @shawn1874 please post on pastebin the full dockerfile and the full ouptut of docker build. 127 means command not found. Did you install csh ?

Comment: The answer is correct.  It turns out that I had a trailing '\' after the final RUN command so ENTRYPOINT was being interpreted by the RUN command instead of being interpreted as a separate DOCKER command.  My original attempt prior to asking this specific question was actually the right approach as you have pointed out.  I just had an error in that Dockerfile.